# Invalid Column name on parameter input

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

Really wrecking my head here and as with many sql mess up I know it is probably something silly and stupid but I just cant seem to get it to work.

I have a stored procedure which is this..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RETURN_DATA](@TABLE_param VARCHAR(7),@COUNTRY_param VARCHAR(2),@FILEDATE_param int,@TTKT_param VARCHAR(6))



AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT @SQL = 'Select * from ' + @TABLE_param + ' WHERE COUNTRY = ' + @COUNTRY_param + ' AND MONTH(Fil_Dte) = ' + cast(@FILEDATE_param as varchar(20)) + ' AND TRNN = '+ @TKTT_param

    EXECUTE(@SQL)


END
```

I'm using it in a vb.net windows form app so applying the parameters there. But trying to run it in SSMS with this

```
exec RETURN_DATA @COUNTRY_param='GB',@FILEDATE_param=4,@TABLE_param='table30',@TTKT_param='000000'
```

Returns the error
`Invalid column name 'GB'.` which i find strange as I never called for a column called `GB` but called for rows with `GB` in the column `COUNTRY` in my where clause?

I know this hopefully is a simple fix so any help would be greatly appreciated and also even if you think theres a better way to go about writing the SP!

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Tip: Print out the SQL rather than executing it and you should immediately see the problem...

Comment: Tip 2: This method of generating SQL is horribly open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I'd recommend parameterising the SQL else you should properly handle escaping quotes

Comment: Relevant... https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend parameterising the SQL which will guard against SQL injection and you don't have to worry about escaping quotes as below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RETURN_DATA](@TABLE_param VARCHAR(7),@COUNTRY_param VARCHAR(2),@FILEDATE_param int,@TTKT_param VARCHAR(6))

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @SQL = 'Select * from ' + @TABLE_param + ' WHERE COUNTRY = ''' + @COUNTRY_param + ''' AND MONTH(Fil_Dte) = ' + cast(@FILEDATE_param as varchar(20)) + ' AND TRNN = '''+ @TKTT_param +''''

    EXECUTE(@SQL)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sp_executesql to run dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (4000);

SET @SQL = '
Select *
from ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_param) + '
WHERE COUNTRY = @COUNTRY_param 
AND MONTH(Fil_Dte) = @FILEDATE_param
AND TRNN = @TTKT_param
';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, 
N'@COUNTRY_param VARCHAR(2), @FILEDATE_param int, @TTKT_param VARCHAR(6)', 
@COUNTRY_param, @FILEDATE_param, @TTKT_param;
```

[sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)